# converting awk command line to awk file

Tags: awk

This works:

```
awk -F2 '{if (NF > 1) { if (substr($1,0,2) == "..") printf ("%.2f 2%s", ((50*length($1))/1000) , $2); else printf("%s2%s",$1,$2); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf("2%s",$i) } else if (substr($1,0,2) == "..") printf("%.2f",((50*length($1))/1000)); else printf("%s",$1); printf("\n");}'-f debugconsole > debugconsoleWithCount
```

But when I make the file countdots.awk as follows:

```
BEGIN {
    if (NF > 1) 
    { 
        if (substr($1,0,2) == "..") 
            printf ("%.2f 2%s", ((50*length($1))/1000) , $2);
        else 
            printf("%s2%s",$1,$2)
        for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) 
            printf("2%s",$i) 
    } 
    else 
        if (substr($1,0,2) == "..") 
        printf("%.2f",((50*length($1))/1000)); 
    else printf("%s",$1); 
        printf("\n");
}
```

and run it like this:

```
awk -F2 -f countdots4.awk debugconsole > debugconsoleWithCount
```

I get an empty debugconsoleWithCount file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **BEGIN** block in `awk` is executed only **once**, *before* the first input record is read.

An **END** rule is executed only **once**, *after* all the input is read.

In your transformation, since you put everything in `BEGIN` block, it becomes a no-op since values of `NF`, `$1`, `$2` .. etc is not even set. Hence you get an empty file. If you remove it it should work fine.

`BEGIN` and `END` blocks are not mandatory so you don't have to keep them in your `awk` script. `BEGIN` is often used to print titles, headers, initializing variables to particular values etc. `END` block is often used to do final processing after entire input is read.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this has to do with not understanding BEGIN and END.

I took out BEGIN and it does what I want.

Should I delete this from stackoverflow? let me know.

Comment: Either give [jaypal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23529229/368630) credit (although it appears they answered your question after you answered it), or wait a few days, and give yourself credit. Don't delete the post because it'll help others. Get rid of the _bash_, _program-files_, and _command-line_ tags and in the _awk-formatting_ tag. It'll help people searching with tags.